# How to deserialize Json correctly in c#

Tags: c#, json

Good afternoon.
I need to deserialize the fields in JSON so that I can work with them as variables. I wrote a getter and setter for fields, loaded json from the url, but at the deserialization stage I get an error

> "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'GetDataFromUrl.JsonData' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."

How do I correctly specify data for deserialization?

This type of JSON:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2020-01-30",
        "CountProblem": 10,
        "Users": 8,
    }
]
```

Code:

```
class JsonData
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int CountProblem { get; set; }
    public int Users { get; set; }
}

    class Report
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        var urlResponse = client.DownloadString("//my url");

        JsonData jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(urlResponse);

        DateTime date = jsondata.Date;
        int problemCount = jsondata.CountProblem;
        int Users = jsondata.Users;

        Console.WriteLine(Date + "," + CountProblem + "," + Users);
    }
```

Comment: Checking your json data, you get an Array<JsonData> and not just JsonData. Might this be the issue?

Comment: @Paul, hi, can I deserialize an array and get the fields in the array as variables?

Comment: This should work JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonData>>(urlResponse); And then check whether it has an element and access jsonData[0].Date, etc. Nevertheless if you actually don't want it to be a list, you should sent one, but instead just a single object.

Comment: Paul, thank you, everything worked out, I was able to extract the data as I needed. It turned out to be difficult for me, I only know the basics of c so far#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json string represents array not a single object, so try:

```
List<JsonData> jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonData>>(urlResponse);
```

Comment: maybe using List will work for me, but how can I extract the "Date, Count Problem, Users" fields from List use them as variables with their DateTime and Int types?

Comment: Guru Stron, thank you, everything worked out, I was able to extract the data as I needed. It turned out to be difficult for me, I only know the basics of c so far#

Comment: NP, glad it helped.